# Unsupported type 'property' in file logback.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, logback, android-gradle-plugin

I want to use logback-android in Android project. Here is what I have done

I have copied the **jar** files in **libs** folder

- logback-android-1.1.1-2.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar

and have logback.xml in **assets** folder

```
<configuration debug="true">
    <property name="LOG_DIR" value="/mnt/sdcard/com.sf.quid/logs" />

    <!-- Create a logcat appender -->
    <appender name="LOG_CAT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.android.LogcatAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%msg</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- Rolling Appender -->
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <!-- File location -->
        <file>${LOG_DIR}/quidpos.log</file>

        <!-- Only log error messages to log file --> 
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>DEBUG</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>

        <!-- Rolling Policy -->     
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/quidpos.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <minIndex>1</minIndex>
            <maxIndex>1</maxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>

        <!-- Message encoder -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- Log level - change this to ERROR on release -->
    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="LOG_CAT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

and here is dependencies section from **build.gradle** file

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

I am using Android Studio 0.6.1 and Gradle 1.12(Android plugin 0.11.+), and when I try the Clean project, Run, etc options it results in the following error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':multipos:mergeDebugResources'.
Unsupported type 'property' in file C:\Users\Jagmohan\AndroidStudioProjects\MultiPOS\multipos\src\main\res\assets\logback.xml
```

If anyone can identify the potential problem, please answer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your **assets** directory is in the wrong place. It should be `src\main\assets`, not `src\main\res\assets`.

It's trying to read your XML file as a resource file and is throwing an error since it's not a valid Android resource file.