# Android Studio, Gradle Fail to build local html

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

i put a html in Android's assets folder. i got this error.

My IDE version: Android studio beta 0.8.5

gradle : classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>   Unsupported type 'body' in file /Users/KingWu/AndroidStudioProjects/Pappetite_Android/Pappetite2/app/src/main/res/assets/about.html

The html file:

```
<html>
<body>
  <h1>About</h1>
  <p>Hello World</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just find a solution. i place the "assets" folder in a wrong place.

[Unsupported type 'property' in file logback.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216582/unsupported-type-property-in-file-logback-xml)

Answer (score 1):

Please try to change your gradle build version:

from: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'`

to : `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+'`